# If condition is met trigger will fire and clone the record to Salesforce Standard Object

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

TriggerHandler class:

```
 public static void onBeforeUpdate(Map<Id, Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> oldMap, Map<Id, Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> newMap){

   List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> ApptusAgreementList = 
        [Select Id, Name, APT_Contract_Number__c, Apttus__Status__c, Apttus__Status_Category__c  FROM Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c
         WHERE Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'In Effect' and Apttus__Status__c = 'Activated' ];

   List<Contract> contractsToBeUpdatedList = new List<Contract>();

    for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c ApptusAgreement : ApptusAgreementList){
        Contract contractsToBeUpdated = New Contract();
      //  contractsToBeUpdated.Id = ApptusAgreement.Id; 
        contractsToBeUpdated.Name = ApptusAgreement.Name;
     // contractsToBeUpdated.ContractNumber = ApptusAgreement.APT_Contract_Number__c; // Apptus ContractNumber is Text while in Contract it is auto number
       contractsToBeUpdated.Status = ApptusAgreement.Apttus__Status__c;
       contractsToBeUpdated.Status_Category__c  = ApptusAgreement.Apttus__Status_Category__c;

        contractsToBeUpdatedList.add(contractsToBeUpdated);

    }

    upsert contractsToBeUpdatedList; }
```

Trigger :

```
  trigger APT_AgreementSyncTrigger on Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c (after 
 delete, after insert, after undelete, after update, before delete, before 
  insert, before update) {
if(trigger.isBefore) {
    if(trigger.isInsert) {

    } else if(trigger.isUpdate) {
        APT_AgreementSyncTriggerHandler.onBeforeUpdate(trigger.oldMap, trigger.newMap);
    } else if(trigger.isDelete) {

    }

} else if(trigger.isAfter) {
    if(trigger.isInsert) {

    } else if(trigger.isUpdate) {

    } else if(trigger.isDelete) {

    } else if(trigger.isUndelete) {

    }
}}
```

Comment: Trigger does not have compile error but when I have update the record to meet the condition, It has an error an rigger does not work.

Comment: This is my error: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger APT_AgreementSyncTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: APT_AgreementSyncTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FAILED_ACTIVATION, Choose a valid contract status and save your changes. Ask your admin for details.: [Status]: Class.APT_AgreementSyncTriggerHandler.onBeforeUpdate: line 49, column 1, This is the line 49, upsert contractsToBeUpdatedList;

Answer (score 1):

You are doing DML operation on before update.You cant do any DML operation on before update.
***I think your trigger has to be written in "after update"***

***Just call this Line of code like this:***

```
 if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isAfter){
 APT_AgreementSyncTriggerHandler.onBeforeUpdate(trigger.oldMap, 
 trigger.newMap);
 }
```

Please try to use OR condition your trigger.Instead of making else if ladder

***Mistakes:***

- ***You are directly querying the "ApptusAgreementList", but You are passing trigger.oldmap and newmapvalues.But Where you are using it your  class "APT_AgreementSyncTriggerHandler"?!!!!.***

  - **DML operation on Before Update Event**

> Please check salesforce trailhead trigger basics:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers

---

***Please use this trigger for your reference:***

***Trigger:***

You haven't given brief description about your trigger.But still I had written few things,I hope it will helpful to you

```
      trigger APT_AgreementSyncTrigger on Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c (after 
     Update) {
     APT_AgreementSyncTriggerHandler.onAFterUpdate(trigger.new);
     }
```

---

***class:***

```
   public static void APT_AgreementSyncTriggerHandler(List <
   Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c > ApptusAgreementList) {
   set < id > apptusId = new set < id > ();
    List < Contract > contractsToBeUpdatedList = new List < Contract > ();
      for (Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c ac: ApptusAgreementList) {
       apptusId.add(ac.id);
      }
   List < Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c > ApptusAgreementList = [Select Id, 
  Name, APT_Contract_Number__c, Apttus__Status__c,
    Apttus__Status_Category__c FROM Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c
       WHERE Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'In Effect'
     and Apttus__Status__c =
     'Activated'
    and id in: apptusId
 ];

     if (!ApptusAgreementList.isEmpty()) {
   for (Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c ApptusAgreement: ApptusAgreementList) {
      Contract contractsToBeUpdated = New Contract();
    //  contractsToBeUpdated.Id = ApptusAgreement.Id;   //You need to link Contract and aggrement  
   contractsToBeUpdated.Name = ApptusAgreement.Name;
    contractsToBeUpdated.Status = ApptusAgreement.Apttus__Status__c;
     contractsToBeUpdated.Status_Category__c =
        ApptusAgreement.Apttus__Status_Category__c;
    contractsToBeUpdatedList.add(contractsToBeUpdated);
   }
 }
  if (!contractsToBeUpdatedList.isEmpty()) {
   update ontractsToBeUpdatedList;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Accdg to you, after update, so this should be in? Is it correct? if(trigger.isUpdate || trigger.isAfter){
 APT_AgreementSyncTriggerHandler.onAfterUpdate(trigger.oldMap, 
 trigger.newMap);
 }

Comment: I just Updated my answer. "OnafterUpdate"its a method name...you can any specific name

Comment: The Edit was successful however, there is clone Salesforce contract record was not created. What I have missed here?

Comment: How to make the assigning of values to clone dynamic?

Comment: How to make the assigning of values to clone record dynamic?